# chartOptions.redraw is not a function in highcharts using angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, redraw, angular-highcharts

This is the html code

```html
<highcharts-chart
  *ngIf="!isLoading"
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  [(update)]="updateChart"
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"
></highcharts-chart>
```

enter code here

```js
This is the typescriptcode


 onTogglevolume() {
    this.chartOptions.series[2].visible = !this.chartOptions.series[2].visible;

    this.chartOptions = {
      ...this.chartOptions
    };
    this.chartOptions.redraw();

  }
```

```js
These are import statements

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { Options } from "highcharts";
import StockModule from 'highcharts/modules/stock';
StockModule(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Please reproduce your case on the online editor with an explanation of what is wrong. You can start from this template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Please find the stackblitz link attached https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-wfbtbo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. I am not able to redraw the chart on volumetoggle function call

Comment: Pattinson Mj, I am afraid that the demo which you have shared doesn't work.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel here is the working demo and the issue is i am not able to get the color for column chart after volume toggle or click on any buttons.Initially on load the column chart is getting applied color but after that its not working.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-mfcrew?file=src%2Fapp%2FdataService.ts

Answer (score 1):

The load event is only fired once at the begging so it's not the perfect place for more dynamic changes. Instead of this, I suggest using some other event. I guess you are going to calculate the colour of each column after changing the time range. In this case, you should use for example the `afterSetExtremes` events as I did it in the demo.
I also have created a separate method called `colorVolume`. Inside using the chart reference I used the point update method to change the first column colour.

**Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-fvtyrx

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update**