# The color for volume chart using highcharts is not getting applied

Tags: angular, highcharts, colors, candlestick-chart

Here is the demo link of the issue as we can see the column chart(volume) is by default having a skyblue color and on hover its changing the color i want that effect on load only.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-mfcrew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of topic linked below, please refer the answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889389/chartoptions-redraw-is-not-a-function-in-highcharts-using-angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chartOptions.redraw is not a function in highcharts using angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889389/chartoptions-redraw-is-not-a-function-in-highcharts-using-angular)